# angular, fb dashboard(message board), how to setting url in component templete

Tags: angular, facebook

for example,set the fb sdk in `app.module` `constructor()` :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/zh_TW/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and set this `<div>` in web:

```
<div  *ngIf="list">
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.myurl/{{list.link}}" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5"></div>
</div>
```

when I set the `data-href="http://www.myurl/mylink"`, this is work.

but, when I replaced the templete parameter `{{list.link}}` the `data-href="http://www.myurl/{{list.link}}"`, is not work.

the error message :

```
compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'href' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

I have set the `*ngIf="list"`

I have confirmed that this `{{list.link}}` value is not empty.

Comment: `href` is the property of `anchor tag`, but not `div`

Comment: `href` is not `data-href`?